# Documentation on __TABLES__ and __TABLES_SUMMARY__ and other double underscore metadata (bigquery)

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm diving into metadata available on datasets and tables in BigQuery.

There is enough documentation on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro

But I can't find any on `__TABLES__`, `__TABLES_SUMMARY__`.
Where can I find information on this?
Are there any other double underscore functions like that?

What I'm using until now:

```sql
select * from `<project>.<dataset>.__TABLES__`
select * from `<project>.<dataset>.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
```

Answer (score 1):

`__TABLES__` and `__TABLES_SUMMARY__` is officially removed from Google BigQuery documentation and is not further in use. It was replaced with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES on May 2021.

Henceforth, to get the metadata of the tables it is advised to use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`.
For reference as you mentioned [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables) documentation is followed.

Comment: Hey Sakshi,
Thank you so much for this info. I was looking for the same.

Do you have the official release note/Update where Google announces that the __TABLE__ is no longer supposed to be used?