# number of rows of all tables in a bigquery dataset

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset with many tables. Is there an easy way to query an output that displays the table_name and the number of rows in that table without having to do count(*) on each table in the dataset?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do it, querying the metadata:

```
SELECT
  dataset_id,
  table_id,
  # Convert size in bytes to GB
  ROUND(size_bytes/POW(10,9),2) AS size_gb,
  # Convert creation_time and last_modified_time from UNIX EPOCH format to a timestamp
  TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time) AS creation_time,
  TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time) AS last_modified_time,
  row_count,
  # Convert table type from numerical value to description
  CASE
    WHEN type = 1 THEN 'table'
    WHEN type = 2 THEN 'view'
  ELSE
  NULL
END
  AS type
FROM
  project_id.dataset_id.__TABLES__
ORDER BY
  size_gb DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

You may get the metadata using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE` by using below query:

```sql
SELECT table_schema, table_name, total_rows from your-project-id.`region-REGION`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE;
```

You may refer to this [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-table-storage) documenation for more information when retrieving this kind of metadata.

Please note that when using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE`, the query must include a **region qualifier**. If not specified, the default region being used in the query is **US**.

It is mentioned in this [Scope and Syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-table-storage#scope_and_syntax) documentation for `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE` that when you do not specify any region, the metadata is *retrieved from all region*, however, during testing, the behavior of the query only retrieves from region **US** just like in this [scope and syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-datasets-schemata#scope_and_syntax) documentation for `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`. I think, the documentation for `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE` syntax should be updated.

In addition, please note that `__TABLES__` is officially removed from **Google BigQuery** documentation because it is already deprecated as also mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72186250/17720354) similar SO post. It is better to use [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro) when retrieving **BigQuery metadata** since this will be the one to be supported by Google moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and tested Standard BigQuery query to get the all tables count associated with a dataset `dataset_name` in a project as `project_name`

```
#standardSQL
SELECT table_id, row_count  FROM `project_name.dataset_name.__TABLES__`
```

As in the public project `bigquery-public-data` and dataset `baseball`

```
#standardSQL
SELECT table_id, row_count  FROM `bigquery-public-data.baseball.__TABLES__`
```

Result:

```
table_id        row_count
games_post_wide  8676
games_wide       761618
schedules        2431
```

[image]