# Using FOR SYSTEM_TIME for all tables in a dataset - BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to query row counts over all tables in my dataset using `SYSTEM_TIME` logic. I wrote a CTE to identify each table in my dataset. My attempt below is a little psudocode inspired. I am not quite sure how to pass the logic in for each table. This is for BigQuery. Does anyone reading know how I might be able to rewrite this query to achieve a historical row count for every table?

```
WITH tables AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM `dataset`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES)

SELECT tables.table_name, count(*) AS row_count
FROM tables
FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR);
```

The closest I can get throws me an error statement:

`FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF cannot be used with tables defined in WITH clause`

I know that the timestamp logic does work for a single table at a time, but the challenge is to run the same logic for all tables in a dataset.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM `projectid.dataset.tablename`
FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 10 HOUR)
```

Comment: To do what you want to do requires "dynamic sql" (a sql script that writes its own sql - then runs that) but "dynamic sql" isn't allowed in bigquery.  Take a look at this, maybe it will help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73392837/number-of-rows-of-all-tables-in-a-bigquery-dataset  **OR** you could use a python script to iterate through the list of tables and run the multiple sql queries

Comment: Thanks Paul for your input here. I had wondered about python but was hoping to keep it in dbt (we're version < 1.3 so can't use python without conflicting upgrades with other packages). Perhaps a standalone python script is the way go.

Comment: Hi @Kasrel, Can you confirm if the issue is resolved or not ?

Comment: @PaulMaxwell This suggestion did resolve my query. I went ahead and wrote a python script and threw in a bit of threading to speed up the routine. Thanks for the help.